# Browser is getting hang up on loading of over 800 markers on google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am facing a strange problem in loading markers on google maps dynamically it is showing markers correctly but sometimes browser is getting hanged up especially mozilla, which I could not understand why

Below is live url

http://plana.pro/map_project/map_project.php

You can check it by clicking  city (blue icon) to load markers, it will show you properties

Can anyone help me in getting this problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using V3 api then kill the map before loading new markers, then initialize the map again and plot new markers. So it will save time and increase performance little bit.

In V2 api you can use `map.clearOverlay()` to remove all markers at a time...